# Why would anyone think that Zeref is dead?

Tags: fairy-tail

My question is a spoiler itself, you are required to be in/past Alvarez arc.

> Why would anyone think that Zeref is dead? He is right there in Alvarez a king as obvious as the sun, so how could the people in Ishgar seriously miss such a fact?

Put simply, that's all I want to know. Many people thought he was dead, others that he was simply dormant because of his low profile.

> But we know that Zeref said that he wasn't dormant at all himself. So why would people even think that? He was right there all along in Alvarez

Comment: he is known by different name in different places and he is so old that no body remember him or know him pretty well in present

Comment: @mirroroftruth the people in Alvarez know who he is.

Comment: IIRC they don't, they know him as emperor sapprigan or something but the Zeref

Comment: @mirroroftruth can u post a detailed answer with reference

Answer (score 1):

[Zeref Dragneel](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Zeref_Dragneel) is 400+ years old, very few people know him and fewer than that who know his face or has seen him.

In Chapter 208: Death Preying, neither Elfman nor Evergreen recognize Zeref. Even Natsu doesn't remember him. Marijane seems to know a little about Zeref.

[image]

> But we know that Zeref said that he wasn't dormant at all himself.

I don't know where did you find this information but, for some years he was inactive or in sleeping state. He awaken in Tenrou Island arc when he realizes Acnologia is coming.

As for [Alvarez](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Alvarez_Empire), He is known as Emperor Spriggan.

> Zeref created this empire for the sole purpose of defeating Acnologia, obtaining Fairy Heart, and annihilating Ishgar.[4](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Ten_Wizard_Saints) His plans regarding with Fairy Heart once captured was to relive his life with the Time Magic, Neo Eclipse. A plan the Spriggan 12 were not aware of.

When [Makarov](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Makarov_Dreyar) visit Alvarez to visit the Emperor Spriggan, he get shocked seeing Zeref as Emperor. Which also shows that how little the information of Zeref is available in present world. Makarov is one of the [Ten Wizard Saints](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Ten_Wizard_Saints).

[image]

The image is from chapter 444: Emperor Spriggan, shocking face of Makarov when he sees Zeref as Emperor.

Comment: See chapter 250 page 4

Comment: first of all you should had mentioned that information in your question and look at same chapter page 3 where he says he is awoken, so the question would be which part was sleeping and which part never slept.

Comment: I think we have to wait then. Maybe there will be filler in the anime or something. It is unclear

Comment: As your wish, i think filler part is not good for reference and the awoken and sleeping part has different meaning, not pointing the same place, if it has then your question should be modified

Comment: I am saying that thing looks like some plothole. I am assuming things will be clarified once the Alvarez arc comes out on the anime. It may be more clear.